# how to only submit data change in react hook form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I am using the 'editData' function to send an API request, and I am using React Hook Form. However, React Hook Form sends all fields when I submit the form. I only want to send the fields that have changed. How can I achieve this? Thank you for your assistance

Comment: Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RHF maintains a `dirtyFields` form state that you can compare your form values against to filter out unmodified fields.

There are several ways to do this, but here's one:

```
// Map RHF's dirtyFields over the `data` received by `handleSubmit` and return the changed subset of that data.
export function dirtyValues(dirtyFields: object | boolean, allValues: object): object {
  // If *any* item in an array was modified, the entire array must be submitted, because there's no way to indicate
  // "placeholders" for unchanged elements. `dirtyFields` is `true` for leaves.
  if (dirtyFields === true || Array.isArray(dirtyFields))
    return allValues;
  // Here, we have an object
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(dirtyFields).map(key => [key, dirtyValues(dirtyFields[key], allValues[key])]));
}
```

This is an accepted answer from a related GitHub discussion you can find [here](https://github.com/orgs/react-hook-form/discussions/1991#discussioncomment-31308)